# ngx chips sorting after editing the chips doesn't work in chrome but working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-chips

I am using ngx chips and I am trying to edit the tags after adding and called a sorting functin to sort them it's working as expected in firefox but not in chrome. is there any browser issue ?

tags.component.html

```
  <tag-input [id]="id" [formControlName]="fieldName" [(ngModel)]='defaultValue' class="form-control" [displayBy]="'text'" (onTagEdited)="onTextChangeInput($event)" (onAdd)="onItemAdded($event)" (onRemove)="onItemRemoved($event)"    [identifyBy]="'text'"></tag-input>
```

tags.component.ts

```
 onTextChangeInput(value:any) {
    if(this.field.defaultValue[value.index] && this.defaultValue[value.index].text){
      this.defaultValue[value.index].text = value.tag.text;
    }
    this.defaultValue = this.sortByText(defaultValue);
}
```

sorting function

```
  sortByText(data:any):any{
    let nameA:any;
    let nameB:any;
    let returnedValue:any =   data.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
      if(this.field.valueType !== 'string'){
        nameA = a.text.toUpperCase();
        nameB = b.text.toUpperCase();
      }
      else{
        nameA = a.toUpperCase();
        nameB = b.toUpperCase();
      }
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    })
    return returnedValue;
  }
```

It's work as expected in firefox browser but not in chrome

Comment: First thing: Please do not use [(ngModel)] together with a formControl. The next thing is that formControlName should be used without [ and ] because it expects a string. Next hint: Do not use any type when you are not expecting an any. Next thing: please provide more code

Comment: Next thing is: What does it mean "it does not work"? Do you have any console errors? What is the expected behavior and how does chrome differ from this behavior? And maybe you should provide some additional information eg a link to the library

Comment: Expected behavior is tags must be sorted after editing. In the firefox browser above code is working correctly but not in the Chrome browser. Let me give you the different behavior of chrome. I have created tags like [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] and I am editing the c->z then expected behavior is to [a,b,d,e,f,g,h,z] but tags are [a,b,z,e,f,g,h,z] but in console, it's showing the expected result [a,b,d,e,f,g,h,z]. I am beginner so I don't know the real issue it' browser issue or ngx-chips or code issue

Comment: Only editing the tags is working fine but sorting after editing is not showing the correct result on the UI screen, but In the console works fine.

Comment: I think I found the issue but not the solution. This may be a plugin issue. when I edited any tag it called the onTextChangeInput function and edit the tags on the basis of the index of edited tags from the UI screen side and sort all the tags but when data flow from the typescript file to the HTML file it edits the tags once again on the basis of the index. That's why it gives the   [a,b,z,e,f,g,h,z] this result on the UI screen but [a,b,d,e,f,g,h,z] result on the console. Can anyone know the solution for this.